# check_box_tag validate for form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a problem with validating either at least one of the checkboxes was clicked before user can continue. My View looks likes this:

View:

```
<%= form_tag("/categories/", :method => "post") do%>
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <li><%= check_box_tag "categories[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %></li>

    </div>      

<%end%>
<%= submit_tag "Weiter", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
```

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

So what happens is that user registeres and gets the screen with all categories which are available in the category model. He then checks those and clicks proceed. On Post categories got associated with users. But how can I validate that the user chooses at least 1 category. If I do something like this it doesn't work:

```
validates_acceptance_of :categories,
:message => "Please take at least one category", :accept => true
```

Comment: Can you please share the schema details.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to validate the presence of categories.

```
validates :categories, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validator

```
  validate :at_least_one_category_selected

  private

  def at_least_one_category_selected
    if self.categories.blank?
      self.errors.add(:categories, "You must select at least one category.")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, In this case I am calling a JS function before submitting the form. This will surely solve your problem.

```
<%= form_tag("/categories/", :method => "post", id: 'add-category-form') do%>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= check_box_tag "categories[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %></li>
  <%end%>
  <%= button_tag "Weiter", :class => 'btn btn-success btn-lg', id: 'add-category-btn', onclick: "validateCategoryPresent()" %>
<%end%>
```

Then in JS,

```
function validateCategoryPresent() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var checkboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("categories[]"));
  if(checkboxes.reduce((acc, curr) => acc || curr.checked, false)){
    $('#add-category-form').submit();
  } else {
    //swal('Error','Please select atleast one channel!','warning');
    alert('Some error!')
  }
}
```

- I called a JS function on the submit click of `form_tag`, (If you are using `sibmit_tag` replace it with `button_tag`)
- I have prevented default behaviour of the submit button
- Then I started to get the elements by its Id/Class or by Name, and checked what ever I want to do in the JS, and then based on my validation Either I am calling submit() on the form ID, or showing the error message.

Note: For showing error message I have used Sweet alert, you can stick with the alert();, but in case If you are looking for better UI, then uncomment my swal() code in JS and comment out alert();
You can read more about [Sweet Alert PopUp](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)